# "myobject" is not Iterable, but my obect is erased

Tags: python, django

hello i have a trouble about Object is not Iterable in django, when i delete a obect, the message from django is 'myobject' object is not iterable.

here my views.py

```
def delete(request, id=None):
    myobject = get_object_or_404(MyObject, id=id)
    myobject.delete()
    context = {'myobject': myobject}
    return render(request, "cat/home.html", context)
```

and here my home.html

```
{% block content %}
        {% for foo in myojbect %}
            {% if foo.name_myobject %}
                <p><a href="{% url 'cat:detail_myobject' id=foo.id %}">{{ foo.name_myobject }}</a></p>
            {% endif %}
            {% if foo.desc %}
                <p>{{ foo.desc }}</p>
                <a href="{% url 'cat:delete_myobject' id=foo.id %}">Delete</a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
```

if i push "delete", Error appears like that " 'myobject' is not iterable" but my object is erased -_-
Thank you sir for help :)

Comment: How are you planning to return `myobject` in your context dictionary after it has been deleted? Also `myobject` is a single model _object_ yet you are trying to access elements of it using `{% for`.

Comment: @Selcuk my plan is, in home.html is list all of myobject, i put {%for in home.html is for looping all object have a button "delete". When I pressed the delete button, the object was erased and instantly returned the page to the home.html.
so, i need {%for%}, right ? or something wrong in my code ?

Comment: Use a `redirect` instead of `render` at the end of your delete view then. I suggest you to read more about Django as you seem to be confused about some basic concepts.

Comment: @Selcuk ah i already think if have to use 'redirect' hahaha
now my problem is solved man, very thank you for your comment. :D
i'm using this code for solved this trouble.

`def delete(request, id=None):
    myobject = get_object_or_404(MyObject, id=id)
    if myobject.delete():
        return redirect('/cat/myobject/')
    context = {'myobject': [myobject]}
    return render(request, "cat/home.html", context)`



Very very thank you man :)

Answer (score 0):

`myobject` is an model instance. You cannot iterate over that. Generally you use `querysets` for iterating over.

Looking at the template code, thats what you want to do. The easiest you can do is pass the object in a list like

`context = {'myobject': [myobject]}` This should work.

Comment: hi sir, i use your Instruction, but still getting error
here the error "Reverse for 'detail_myobject' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'id': None}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cat/myobject/detail/(?P<id>\\d{1,3})$']"
i don't understand the error ._. 
can you explain for me ?
thank you :)

Comment: it means that it cannot match a url with the name 'detail_myobject'

Comment: @ThomasJiang ohm like that. so, what can i do ? any reference for me, sir ?

Comment: It means you can't make url to non-existent model instance, because you deleted it before. If it did, any user coming by that url would receive HTTP 404

Comment: @AlexMashianov oke i see i see. first i load all of my object, and then i delete 1 object, but the page is reload all of my object before i delete 1 object right ?
oke i know the problem, but i have no idea for solution -_-
btw thank you sir for your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

My problem has solved guys, very thank you for @Selcuk and @iamkush for your answer, very usefull :). and this is the code for solved the problem using `redirect` :D

```
def delete(request, id=None):
    myobject = get_object_or_404(MyObject, id=id)
    if myobject.delete():
        return redirect('/cat/myobject/')
    context = {'myobject': [myobject]}
    return render(request, "cat/home.html", context)
```

Thank you guys :)

Comment: No worries. You can also accept your own answer if you like.